# why don't the ng-leave/ng-enter classes get added

Tags: javascript, angularjs

according to the angular docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations

> ".enter - when a new item is added to the list or when an item is
>   revealed after a filter
>
> .leave - when an item is removed from the list or when an item is
>   filtered out"

yet, when I .push({}) or .splice(-1, 1) from an array, neither of those classes are added to the ng-repeat. what's the problem?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <button ng-click="addLine()">
     add
   </button>
   <button ng-click="removeLine()">
     remove
   </button>
  <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
      <div class="preview">{{$index}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.addLine = function(){
        $scope.lines.push({})
    }
    $scope.removeLine = function(){
        $scope.lines.splice(-1, 1)
    }
    $scope.lines = [{
        text: 'res1'},
    {
        text: 'res2'}];
}
```

**as Ted noted in his answer, having actual css styles for .ng-enter / .ng-leave is required, otherwise the ngAnimate module will not add the .ng-enter classes to the DOM elements**

To be more clear, I don't care about actually doing an animation right now. The issue for me here is that the .ng-enter classes don't actually get applied to the class attribute of an element unless you have css styles for .ng-enter

**WORKING PLUNKER
http://plnkr.co/edit/TqpdIy6syikBhAeb5Kw3?p=preview**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For these classes to be added you have to load the animation module in your app.

See [the ngAnimate docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) for how to do this.

First you must load the additional module's .js file:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-animate.js">
```

Then list it as a dependent module of your application:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

The ngAnimate module also **requires** the element to have its transition defined in either the CSS or the JS:

> For CSS transitions, the transition code must be defined within the starting CSS class (in this case .ng-enter). The destination class is what the transition will animate towards.

If you add something like:

```
/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

It should start working.

To be very clear, because the docs don't say this explicitly: If the animation is not defined in either the CSS or the JS, the ngAnimate module won't even add the classes, it will just skip the animation all together.

Comment: Answer updated. The module needs CSS transitions to function.

Comment: the angular.animate.js source is included. my question is not about actually showing css animations. please re-read question. I just want to see the .ng-enter / .ng-leave classes added.

Comment: I believe Angular relies on the CSS to define the duration to have those classes on there, so no CSS transition means 0sec animation means might just skip the classes. I believe it won't work at all without defining the transition through either CSS or JS

Comment: Unless they changed something from 1.3 > 1.4 I remeber you used to see the .ng-enter applied to ng-show directives regardless of wether or not you had any css for them

Comment: any chance you could modify the answer just to note that without the .ng-enter css class existing, even if you include the 'ngAnimate' module, the .ng-enter class will never be applied to the dom

Comment: Agreed it could be more explicit in the docs. I'll update the answer.